# How to prevent gtk frame expansion

Tags: gtk, frame

I am using Gtkmm 3 in Linux with c++.
I want to draw a frame around my ButtonBox that will NOT expand when a resize my window.
This does not work:

```
Button b1("Hello"), b2("World);
ButtonBox bb;
bb.pack_start(b1, PACK_SHRINK);
bb.pack_start(b2, PACK_SHRINK);

Frame frame("My frame");
frame.add(bb)

Window wn;
wn.add(frame);
```

Can anyone tell me what will prevent the frame from expanding when I manually resize the window with my mouse. I want the frame to stay around the buttons, not to frame the entire window!

Answer (score 0):

I just found a way!

```
frame.property_halign() = ALIGN_START;
frame.property_valign() = ALIGN_START;
```